# RNTester : Unable to find React Native files

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator, xbox

I was going through a react-native tutorial and got a suggestion to check [RNTester](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/RNTester)

I followed the steps of cloning and installing mentioned on github. But when I hit the run button on Xcode I get following error:

> error Unable to find React Native files. Make sure "react-native"
>   module is installed in your project dependencies. Process terminated.
>   Press  to close the window

The simulator is also launched with bunch of method names.

[image: RNTester error]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the required things mentioned in official site to run project https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started?

Comment: Yes i did install the prerequisites.

Comment: try simply running `yarn start` from the repo root